# SwiftUI: How can I assign my initializer to a specific object?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I use `UIScrollView.appearance().backgroundColor` to change the background color of my ContentView. But unfortunately, that has the side effect that the colors of my `ModalView()` are not quite normal anymore.

**To solve the problem, I see three possible solutions:**

The first option is somehow to assign the `UIScrollView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.red` only to the first `ScrollView`.

The second would be to find another way to change the background color of my `ContentView()`.

And the third option would be to reset the `UIScrollView.appearance().backgroundColor` in `ModalView()`back to the default setting. (**EDIT: I think now that the third option is not possible**)

And thanks for every answer

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var show_modal: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        UIScrollView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.red // This how I change the backgroundcolor of this View

        return NavigationView {
            ScrollView { // This ScrollView should be affected by the initializer
                VStack(spacing: 12) {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Only unimportant content")
                        Spacer()
                    }
                } .padding(.horizontal).padding(.bottom)
            }

            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Header"))
            .navigationBarItems(
                leading:
                Button(action: { self.show_modal = true }) {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                        .padding(.all, 10)
                } .sheet(isPresented: self.$show_modal) { ModalView() }.padding(.leading, -10)
            )
        }
    }
}

struct ModalView: View { // This should not be affected by the initializer
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @State private var name: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        // UIScrollView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.red // If anyone knows the default value, please enter this here

        return NavigationView {
            Form {
                List {
                    TextField("This is a TextField", text: $name)
                }
            }

            .navigationBarTitle(Text(""), displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            .navigationBarItems(
                leading:
                Button(action: { self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss() }) {
                    Text("Cancel")
                }.padding(.vertical, 5)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

This is my `ModalView()` with the "beautiful" side effects
[image]

**In this picture, you can see what makes me believe that the third option is not possible:**

- The interior of the selected text field is discolored

- The auto-correction suggestions are also discolored

- With dark mode turned on it gets even worse

[image]

Comment: Don't change the appearance of `UIScrollView` then. Apply the modifier to the specific `ScrollView`

Comment: But unfortunately, I can not figure out how to do that.

Comment: Just use the .background(Color.red) modifier on your ScrollView().

Answer (score 3):

Just apply the background colour directly to the scroll view.

```
return VStack{
    ScrollView { // This ScrollView should be affected by the initializer
        Text("Text 1")
    }
        .background(Color.red)
    ScrollView { // This ScrollView should NOT be affected by the initializer
        Text("Text 2")
    }
}
```

Comment: No, that's not the solution to my problem. It may work in the example code above, but as I said before, this is a much-simplified version. And unfortunately, it does not work in my real project. But thanks for the answer anyway. And I have edited the example code a bit to make it more like my real project.

Comment: @MattisSchulte Is there a reason you need to use the `appearance()` API then? You can still override it for individual views.

Comment: Yes, I need the ```appearance()``` API, as this is the easiest way to change the background color of the ContenView, including the navigation bar, when using ```ScrollView``` and ```NavigationView``` together. But you're right that I can still override it for individual views. So if I could find a way to set the Appearance API back to default, my problem would be solved.

Comment: only use appearance() if swiftUI cant achieve what you want. Changing the backgroundcolor of a ScrollView in swiftUI shouldn't be a problem, so there is absolutely no need for appearance()

Comment: @Mamaessen Regrettably, changing the background color when using ```ScrollView``` and ```NavigationView``` is a very big problem. But if you want to know more about this topic, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56923397/how-change-background-color-if-using-navigationview-in-swiftui) is a good question.

Answer (score 1):

The default backgroundcolor for a sheet is secondarySystemBackground.

```
UIScrollView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.secondarySystemBackground
```

Comment: Ok, now after you edit the Question I understand your problem.

Comment: No, that also doesn't work without side effects. But I have added an exact description of the side effects to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify modal view as a specifical case like the following:

```
    UIScrollView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.red //normal 
    UIScrollView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIPresentationController.self]) .backgroundColor = UIColor.white //modal
```

If you want a better result, just specify subclass of UIScrollView.

```
    UIScrollView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    UIScrollView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIPresentationController.self]).backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    UITableView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIPresentationController.self]).backgroundColor = UIColor.secondarySystemBackground
```

Comment: In any case interesting, but unfortunately there are the same problems as in the answer of @Mamaessen

Comment: You still can customize the view to what you expected.