# Scroll Views background colour when placed in a Navigation Stack in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-scrollview

I have two scroll views placed in a `NavigationView`. I want both the ScrollViews to inherit the colour as mentioned in the `onAppear` modifier.

However, when I navigate to the second ScrollView and go back to the first ScrollView, the first view inherits the second ScrollView colour.

```
struct ScrollView1: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                NavigationLink(destination: ScrollView2()) {
                    Text("First View").padding()
                }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }.navigationBarTitle("First")
            .onAppear {
                UIScrollView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.green
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ScrollView2: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Text("Second View").frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        }
        .onAppear {
            UIScrollView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how my first ScrollView will always inherit green and second, gray colour?

Adding ScrollView colour by wrapping inside a ZStack will not collapse NavigationBar from large to inline while scrolling.

Is there any other solution to achieve both i.e, preserving the navigationBar bounce behaviour along with ScrollView colour.

Answer (score -1):

First you can remove `backgroundColor` from `UITableView` and `UIScrollView` (you can do this in `SceneDelegate`, so it will only be executed once):

```
UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
UIScrollView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

Then use `ZStack` to add background colours:

```
struct ScrollView1: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color.green
                ScrollView {
                    NavigationLink(destination: ScrollView2()) {
                        Text("First View").padding()
                    }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                }.navigationBarTitle("asdasd")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct ScrollView2: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.gray
            ScrollView {
                Text("Second View").frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: wrapping scroll view in ZStack and adding colour as such ,breaks the navigationBarTitle bounce behaviour. That's why i tried adding Scroll View colour in the onAppear modifier. Help me in case if both can be achieved together. :)

Comment: You can do the same for your `NavigationView`. Just remove the backgroundColor with `UITableView`. I updated my code with this fix.

Comment: This still does not collapse Navigation Bar from large to inline while scrolling. The colour changes works as expected though.

Comment: pawello is correct, and if you want to handle your navigation bar then use NavigationBarTitle("title", displayMode: automatic)

Comment: But wrapping Navigation View in ZStack, as done above ,will not change the Scroll View1 colour to green. Tried this code but it doesn't serve me the solution :(

Comment: @BeeEm97 It looks like currently there's no solution to your problem: [How change background color if using NavigationView in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56923397/8697793), [Screen Background Color With ScrollView And Navigation Bar SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56923397/8697793).

Comment: Yaa..it seems that swiftUI is not perfect yet !..btw..thanks @pawello2222 :D