# SwiftUI NavigationBar Background Gradient on iPad

Tags: ipad, swiftui, uinavigationbar, gradient

I'm passing my UIKit app to SwiftUI and struggle to make this work.

I want to put a left to right gradient on each navigation bars of my double column iPad display.

I've tried various approach but never quite make it.

Answer (score 2):

Using FRIDDAY's answer from
[How change background color if using NavigationView in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56923397/how-change-background-color-if-using-navigationview-in-swiftui),
I achieved the much appreciated gradient:

```
extension UINavigationController {
    
    override open func viewDidLoad() {
        
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        
        gradient.frame = self.view.bounds
        gradient.colors = [UIColor(Colors.red).cgColor, UIColor(Colors.orange).cgColor]
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
        
        let standard = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        standard.backgroundImage = gradient.toImage()

        let compact = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        compact.backgroundImage = gradient.toImage()

        let scrollEdge = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        scrollEdge.backgroundImage = gradient.toImage()

        self.navigationBar.standardAppearance = standard
        self.navigationBar.compactAppearance = compact
        self.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = scrollEdge
        
    }
    
}

extension CALayer {

    func toImage() -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size)
        self.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return outputImage!
    }
    
}
```

Comment: What's the toImage() functin you're using on the gradient ?

Comment: Ok I guess you have something like this: import Foundation
import QuartzCore
import UIKit

extension CALayer {
    func toImage() -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(frame.size, isOpaque, 0)
        render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return outputImage!
    }
}

Comment: @lorenzo Could you add toImage function?

Comment: @Santiago added in the answer!