# Set View Picker Header Color?

Tags: swiftui, ios15

Is it possible to add background color to the top of a picker view? I'm specifically interested in the area from the top of the view down to just below the navigation bar. I have made all my app tab and navigation views with the same header appearance but haven't had any luck with the pickers.

I would like to set the picker backgrounds to look like this:
[image: I would like the background to look like this view]

Here is a picker view that I would like to add background color.
[image: here is my picker]

Here is what happens when adding call to DrawNavBox() just after the Picker (See code below). I need help pushing the green block to the top of the view.
[image: attempt to add header color to picker]

The code below is what generates the Home Currency green header above

```
 var body: some View {

        GeometryReader { g in
            VStack {

                DrawNavBox(g: g) // draw green header

                Text("Your home currency is:")
                    .padding(.top, g.size.height * 0.10)

                Text("\(base.baseCur.baseCurrency) \(base.baseCur.baseCountry)")
                    .font(.body)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding(15)
                    .background(Color("Dark Green"))
                    .cornerRadius(20)
                    .padding(.trailing, g.size.width * 0.19)
                    .padding(.leading, g.size.width * 0.22)

                Form {
                    Section(header: Text("Select Home Currency")) {

                        Picker("Home Currency", selection: $gotBase) {
                           DrawNavBox(g: g)
                            ForEach(0 ..< currCountry.count, id: \.self) { item in
                                VStack(alignment: .leading) {

                                    Text(currCountry[item])
                                        .font(.subheadline)
                                        .padding(.leading, 25)

                                    HStack {
                                        Text(currSymbol[item])
                                        Text(currName[item])
                                    }
                                    .font(.caption)
                                    .padding(.leading, 25)
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Home Currency"), displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                                    Button(action: {
                // search for new base currency
                self.changeBaseCurrency()

            }) {
                Text ("Save").bold()
            }
            )}
    }
}
```

This is the code I have been using to set the navigation bar area green

```
struct DrawNavBox: View {

   var g: GeometryProxy

   var body: some View {

       ZStack (alignment: .top) {
           Color(.systemGreen)
               .frame(height: (g.safeAreaInsets.top), alignment: .top)
               .ignoresSafeArea()
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: On iOS 16 it does not navigate to select anymore but use popover menu style, so think if it is worth doing.

Comment: That is what I have been afraid of--that the changes to navigation in iOS16 would impact something like this. I think I understand that you are suggesting (iOS15) use of one of the picker style options such as menuPickerStyle. Thanks

Comment: This question has been asked and answered before. Check this out: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56923397/how-change-background-color-if-using-navigationview-in-swiftui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56923397/how-change-background-color-if-using-navigationview-in-swiftui)