# Using a custom background behind NavigationStack in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationstack

This ought to be straightforward enough, but I cannot find out how to place a background behind a NavigationStack. With NavigationView, it was simply a matter of embedding in a ZStack with the background view called before the NavigationView (as described in an older post: [How change background color if using NavigationView in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56923397/how-change-background-color-if-using-navigationview-in-swiftui))
The same technique does not work for me with NavigationStack.
Here's what I have:

```
   struct MyAngularGradient: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            AngularGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.red, .orange , .yellow, .green, .cyan, .blue, .indigo, .purple, .red]), center: .leading)
            AngularGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.red, .orange , .yellow, .green, .cyan, .blue, .indigo, .purple, .red]), center: .leading)
                .offset(x: -8)
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}

var body: some View {
            ZStack{
                MyAngularGradient()
                NavigationStack {
                  ...
                }
                 .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
             } // end ZStack
```

FYI, I've used the same MyAngularGradient()in other apps (with NavigationView)
Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

The closest I've managed to get so far is this:

```
struct MyView: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ZStack {
                Color.pink.ignoresSafeArea()

                List {
                    NavigationLink("Hello") {
                        Text("Hello")
                    }
                }
                .navigationTitle("Title")
            }
        }
        .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
    }

}
```

Which is somewhat dissatisfying for the following reasons:

1. When you scroll up the navigation bar appears, as expected, but ruins the effect imo.

I guess you can experiment changing this in a limited way using `UINavigationBarAppearance()` by updating it in the constructor of the view.

[image: Non-scrolled image of the above]
[image: Scrolled version of the above]

2. You can't apply a background to the whole app if you have multiple `NavigationStackView` based views in a `TabView`.  (My example above was in a `TabView`)
3. When a new view is pushed on the stack the custom background disappears.
4. Only works on iOS 16+ due to the `.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)` modifier.
5. Does not work if you use ForEach to populate the `List`.  Interestingly if you debug the hierarchy with and without the `ForEach` you'll see that SwiftUI adds a new view controller which is opaque in the case of `ForEach`.

Comment: Thank you brindy for taking the time to answer. I tried your suggestion with immediate but limited success. I will keep experimenting, and if/when I get the effect I'm hoping for, I will be sure to update this post. In the meantime, thanks for getting me headed in (what I think is) the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can just apply `.background` to the main content.

- Use `.frame` to extend the size of the main content to the full screen size, if necessary.
- A `ZStack` is not needed.

```swift
NavigationStack {
    Text("NavigationStack")
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(MyAngularGradient())
}
.navigationViewStyle(.stack)
```

Note that the safe area insets are ignored by default when the background is set in this way, see [background(_:ignoresSafeAreaEdges:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/background(_:ignoressafeareaedges:))

[image: Screenshot]